# Python callable() built-in function returns false for an instance method

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am using Python version 3.6.

```
class Pen:
    def write(self):
        print("Writing")

def __call__(self,p):
    print("calling a pen object")

pen1 = Pen()

print(callable(pen1.write()))
```

The above Python example returns the following output

```
Writing
False
```

Why this behaviour? 
Is an instance method not a callable in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pen1.write` is callable, but not the results `pen1.write()`. This will call the method and pass its results (`None`) to the `callable` method as the argument. `None` is not callable.

Try:

```
print(callable(pen1.write))
```